# RDLC report viewer not showing data in the report viewer?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting

I'm using SQLITE database and want to use report viewer for show report in windows application using C#. My code is

```
DataSet ds=rel.show_data1("site_master");
this.reportViewer1.Reset();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("test_rds", ds.Tables[0]);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
reportViewer1.Visible = true;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

But i am unable to view the data on the report page. Kindly help. if you have any useful link please give me because i'm very new to reports. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a IsPostBack on your pageload?

Answer (score 0):

I think You are not provided Path of Report Like

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
```